# How to use custom format in Carbon php?

Tags: php, php-carbon

I'm creating a function that converts given seconds to duration with given format. My example code is:

```php
$format = "HHr(s) iMin(s)";
$seconds = 3600;
echo Carbon::parse($seconds)->format($format); // 0101Thu, 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 +0000(00) 00Jan001(00)
```

What I would like to get is **01Hr(s) 00Min(s)**. But I'm getting above. How should I adjust to use custom format?

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape some characters that not need to parsed as format. To escape just add slash before those chars

Try this:

```
$format = "H\H\\r(\s) i\M\i\\n(\s)";
```

- `\r` is a Carriage Return `\n` is a Line Feed (or new line). To escape that, simply add an extra slash.

Or if use single quote for format you don't need to add extra slash to `\r` and `\n`. for example:

```
$format = 'H\H\r(\s) i\M\i\n(\s)';
```

Comment: While this is correct regarding the given original post code, one should avoid to use `parse` when dealing with timestamp (prefer `Carbon::createFromTimestamp($seconds)`), second it's semantically incorrect to use date to represent a duration and may leads to bugs, prefer to use `CarbonInterval` / `DateInterval`: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-interval

Answer (score 0):

Try `gmdate()` function to convert seconds to time

```
$seconds = 3600;

echo gmdate("H:i:s", $seconds);
```

Comment: Yes. But just want to get the value from Carbon class.